# Display glitches after Windows 7 standby

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I recently formatted my HDD on my Sony Vaio laptop (SVE151C11M).
I reinstalled Windows 7 x64 Home Edition, the necessary drivers (also graphics) and the programs I need.

Now, when my computer leaves standby mode, my graphics card fails horribly.
I did not have this problem before the reinstall and I really need the standby function.

Here's a video of the problem:
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AI-p_6Ll3v8)

If anyone has any suggestions on how I could maybe fix this problem, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Seems like a faulty monitor link, have you tried tilting the monitor to different angles? Or connecting a monitor to the display port?

Comment: This is a pure driver problem you installed the drivers provided by Sony?

Comment: Yeah, I installed the drivers on the page of my laptop model.

Comment: I just reinstalled my graphics driver and it didn't do a thing...